# Refreshing Form in Java ME

Tags: java-me, timertask

I am Developing a `Java ME` Application, Here I want refresh my Form on a particular time interval. I have tried `TimerTask` to re-showing the Form again & again. It works fine, but I think it consumes Memory. So is there any other way to Refresh Form.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `refreshing the Form` ?

Comment: ReFreshing Form means readling of the Form. so that new re-freshed values will be displayed on the form. Just for example if you see the stock prices are updated.

Comment: did you consider displaying "refreshable" parts inside some CustomItem? that one seems to be designed to do stuff like that when you need to stay withion form (as opposed to displaying stuff in Canvas)

Comment: Why don't you simply refresh the fields' values or item's values ?

Comment: if I refresh the field value then how it is going to be in notice , until i reload the Form.

Comment: When you change values in the `Items` in your `Form` the display will be updated automatically. You don't need to refresh the display.

Comment: @SteveO'Connor I wouldn't rely on that too much. [Form API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html) say _updates to the display take place as soon as it is feasible for the implementation to do so_. In my experience, notion of what is **feasible** for MIDP implementor did not always fit app developer expectations... softly speaking

Comment: @gnat yes, I agree that what the system thinks is refreshing may not be what the developer wants. The problem here is that there isn't an API to for the user to refresh a `Displayable` like a `Form`, it's up to the system. A `Form` is not a `Canvas`. You could try `Display.setCurrent(...)` to remind the system you want to display the Form but I can't imagine why that would make it happen any faster than the Form API mentions. The other way would be to rebuild the `Form` but that sounds just plain nasty.

Comment: you are right @gnat , I am using TimerTask to reload the form. But I do not think it is right way to do it

Comment: @SteveO'Connor your point is well taken - `Canvas` is indeed safe bet for reliable animation. I think though that CustomItem with its [invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html#invalidate()) might be worth trying, too. Per my reading of MIDP spec primary design goal of CustomItem API was just to allow a bit more control on rendering to _leak through_ into form items that extend it

Comment: @Lucifer I see. Relaod that way doesn't look ok to me too. Have you tried to paint into CustomItem and use that TimerTask to invoke its [invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html#invalidate())? As opposed to Form reload, _invalidate CustomItem_ kind refresh would be perfectly reasonable to me

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By refreshing, If you mean following things, then there is no need of 
Display.setCurrent() every time you want to refresh form.

1. Add item in Form
2. Remove item from Form
3. Setting a value to a item in the Form. e.g. update StringItem value